# sql query to print users who have different passwords and its count

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a oracle table values as below.

```
UserName       Password         Application
============== ================ ===============
John           cat              gmail
John           cat              ldap
John           dog              yahoo
John           dog              fusion
Rick           boat             oracle
Rick           mat              gmail
Rick           boat             yahoo
Joe            lilly            gmail
Joe            lilly            yahoo
Joe            lilly            oracle
```

I want to query users who have differnt passwords and also its count. I want to have the following as a result.

```
John    cat    2
John    dog    2
Rick    boat   2
Rick    mat    1
```

Comment: oh dear! Storing plaintext passwords.....

Comment: @MitchWheat I guess this just a homework example ... or the owner of a botnet who is just bad at SQL

Comment: Hmm.. Just an example.

Comment: What have you got so far?  Getting the count of password occurrences per user is easy, combining it with users with multiple passwords a bit less so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick, of course, is knowing how to combine the two parts of the query:

```
SELECT user_password.UserName, user_password.Password, COUNT(*)
FROM user_password
JOIN (SELECT UserName
      FROM user_password
      GROUP BY UserName
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Password) > 1) multiple_passwords
  ON multiple_passwords.UserName = user_password.UserName
GROUP BY user_password.UserName, user_password.Password
ORDER BY user_password.UserName
```

(Have a [working SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba9ae/6)!)

The sub-select (inner query) finds `UserName`s with more than one password (and gets unique rows, too).  Outside of that, it's a standard "count of times entry is reused" query.

(And by the way, I hope these aren't real passwords... #shudders#)

Comment: Excellent. This is what I wanted precisely. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07aad/10)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH password_counts AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         UserName,
         Password,
         COUNT( DISTINCT Password ) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserName ) AS number_of_passwords,
         COUNT( Password ) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserName, Password ) AS count_per_password
  FROM   SecurityHole
)
SELECT UserName,
       Password,
       count_per_password
FROM   password_counts
WHERE  number_of_passwords > 1
ORDER BY UserName, Password
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07aad/10/0)**:

```
| USERNAME | PASSWORD | COUNT_PER_PASSWORD |
|----------|----------|--------------------|
|     John |      cat |                  2 |
|     John |      dog |                  2 |
|     Rick |     boat |                  2 |
|     Rick |      mat |                  1 |
```

Comment: +1 - I didn't think of this version.  Of course, that's because I'm used to DB2 on V6, which doesn't allow `COUNT(*)` as the aggregate...

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
SELECT username,password,COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM t GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT password>1))
GROUP by username,password
```

you can optimize it if you'll use with clause to prevent the table from being read twice.

Comment: Actually, a CTE will probably still cause the table to be read twice.  You might get better performance if you used that sort of table-reference in the query, though.

Comment: Its missing a closing bracket for `COUNT(DISTINCT password` and the trailing `GROUP BY username, password` clause.